# The input textbox is not letting me insert a value

Tags: reactjs

This is the updated code now. Let me know if something is not correct as I am able to compile but the issue still persists

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.polyglot = PolyglotFactory.getPolyglot(props.pageLang);
        this.state = {
          otherInvestorSubtype: props.otherInvestorSubtype,
        };
      }

      shouldRenderOtherSubtype = () => this.props.otherInvestorSubtype === OTHER_INVESTOR_SUBTYPE;

      shouldRenderSubtype = () => {
        const { investorTypeOptions, investorType } = this.props;
        const investorTypeOption = investorTypeOptions.find(({ value }) => value === investorType);
        return investorTypeOption !== undefined && investorTypeOption.subtypes.length > 0;
      }
      handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          otherInvestorSubtype: e.target.value,
        });
        this.props.handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange();
      }
      renderSelectOtherSubtype = () => {
        const { handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange,
          showError, registerChildValidator, pageLang } = this.props;
        const { otherInvestorSubtype } = this.state;
        return (
          <ValidatedText
            name="investor_subtype_other"
            value={otherInvestorSubtype}
            onChange={this.handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange}
            showError={showError}
            registerValidation={registerChildValidator}
            validation={validation(this.polyglot.t('inputs.investorTypes'), pageLang, rules.required())}
            required
          />
        );
      }
```

This is the only information I have got for this. Let me know if something is missing.

Comment: can you provide the parent component, which handles the text change and send the props to this component?

Comment: @salix : I updated the post. I think that might help

Comment: This does not seem like the parent component. The parent component makes use of the latest provided investorTypes and <InvestorType /> component.

Comment: @salix Can you have a look now. The code is segregated in constants, container and component folder. If this is not what you want, let me know in which folder I can find. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've set the textbox value as otherInvestorSubtype which is provided by the props. This way, the component (so that the textbox value) is not updated on textbox value change. You need to store the otherInvestorSubtype value provided by props in the InvestorType component's state as the following, in order to update the InvestorType component every time the user types something:

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.state {
    otherInvestorSubtype: props.otherInvestorSubtype
  }
}
```

change the renderSelectOtherSubtype method as the following:

```
renderSelectOtherSubtype = () => {
    const { handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange, showError, registerChildValidator, pageLang } = this.props;
    const { otherInvestorSubtype } = this.state
    return (
      <ValidatedText
        ...
        value={ otherInvestorSubtype }
        onChange={ this.handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange }
        ...
      />
    );
}
```

and finally handle the textbox change on this component:

```
handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        otherInvestorSubtype: e.target.value
    });

    this.props.handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange();
}
```

Hope this helps, and sorry if I have any typos.

Comment: I made 3 changes as told by you. The only error I am getting is 'handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: You put this method in InvestorType component, and changed the onChange prop value as the following right?

onChange={ this.handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange }

Comment: renderSelectOtherSubtype = () => {
    const { handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange,
      showError, registerChildValidator, pageLang } = this.props;
    const { otherInvestorSubtype } = this.state;
    return (
      <ValidatedText
        name="investor_subtype_other"
        value={otherInvestorSubtype}
        onChange={this.handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange}
        showError={showError}
        registerValidation={registerChildValidator}
        validation={validation(this.polyglot.t('inputs.investorTypes'), pageLang, rules.required())}
        required
      />
    );
  }

Comment: Alriht this is just a warning. Remove handleOtherInvestorSubtypeChange in the first line of the method, because you're not using this method on renderSelectOtherSubtype anymore.

Comment: I have put the code snippet which I changed in the main post. You can refer from that as I was not able to put that in comments.

Comment: I removed that part and compiled successfully but the issue still persists. Can you please check the snippet in the main post if everything is alright there?

Comment: You've put the code I provided in the child component (InvestorType) right? If so, you now should be able to edit the textbox value.

Comment: I think so. I put the code in the same place where these functions were already defined. I am very new to this technology. Literally I am a layman here. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I have put the updated code in the main post. Can you please have a look if I did changes exactly like you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it seems okay now. Unfortunately I cannot test it on my machine.

Comment: The issue still persists though. If you get some other idea or workaround, please let me know.